# Java / Gradle: Prevent Access to Code

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java project with Gradle as build environment.

Simplifying my scenario: 
I have a module called `Utils` and one of its interfaces is `TimeProvider` which is implemented by either a real time provider (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) or a logic time provider (incrementing a counter). Another example is instead of sleeping for some time, I can just increment the timestamp. The goal is to run tests independently of the current time. An example use case is to be able to stop at break points without worrying aobut the time to progress and disrupting my tests.
(BTW if you have a betteer way to do do, I would appreciate any insight).

My question is how to force all the parts in the code to use this infrastructure and not the real Java time solutions (`Thread.sleep`, `System.currentTimeMillis`, etc.) 
I want to prevent a scenario where a programmer accidently writes a code that uses the real Java time instead of my infrastructure.
One option is to use a Security Manager but this is tricky because the error will be catched "some time" during run time. 
I prefer a way to catch this during compile time.

I wonder if there is a way, maybe in Gradle to forbid some modules use part of Java code? Maybe there is another way to do so?

Thanks,

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do that at runtime. But you could use a custom PMD or Checkstyle rule to check that at build time. It feels strange to desire a runtime solution: not using your TimeProvider shouldn't have any impact on the production code: it only makes the unit tests harder.

Comment: My goal is to catch this at compile time. PMD rule is indeed a good idea, and I will add it. Probably the main influence of not using my TimeProvider is destroying unit testing, and this is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Ah. Then why does your question say "I prefer a way to catch this during run time."?

Comment: No problem. That happens to me all the time :)